# no python support in vim console distribution Windows 10

Tags: python, vim

After installing both python 2 and python 3 (32bit versions), on Windows 10, curiously only GVim has both python and python3 checked on invoking `:version`; the console version of vim does not seem to have python support.

How come that GVim does has support, but the console version doesn't?

**Note.**

The Vim distribution I installed is also 32 bit, like the Python distributions.